# How to sort a collection by row in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, hapi.js

I am using MongoDB with hapi.JS. I have a collection which contains few rows in the schema. I want to sort the rows in either asc order or desc order but want to mention it in the URI. for example the URI should look something like this

```
/api/v1/customers?sort=name&direction=asc&limit=30
```

How can I sort this collection by asc or desc order and limit can be fixed or flexible as well.
I have defined like this as of now but even if I mention the sort in URI it gives the output only in asc order.

```
 Models.Account.find(criteria,projection,{skip:5,limit:5},function(err,resp){
                if(err)
                callbackRoute(err);
                else 
                callbackRoute(err,resp);
            }).sort({[_id]:"asc"});
```

Comment: if you want to make limit variable on what ever you supply in your URI, you cant insert fixed numbers, same for sorting direction. read out the variables values from your URI using express or whatever you use and insert them, like limit: mylimit and sort({ [_id]: mydirection })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.yourcollection.find(...).sort({ name:1 }).limit(30)
```

or with dynamic values:

```
// following is ECMA 6 only
// get params and make sure values are what you expect (check for injection) + direction must be = "asc" || "desc"
db.yourcollection.find(...).sort({ [sort]: direction }).limit(30)
```

Comment: for limit I have tried to use plugin hapi-pagination with JOI validation but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: pagination is an own issue, if you use plain mongo you would either have to use skip() or implement your own logic. however, without pagination, this is enough.

Comment: what if I want to have both asc and desc as an option and leave it upto the user to mention it in the URI according to the requirement?

Comment: but again it will be restricted as whatever I mention here according to that only rows will be sorted in the database before returning the result.But I am looking for more flexible one where I can mention in the endpoint instead

Comment: well, then please say clearly what you want in your question. that not what you asked for. of course only rows are sorted, what else? its the only thing that can be sorted, nothing else would make sense.

Comment: Reframed the question

Comment: Now I am trying to do this. Refer this post for the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917652/how-do-i-sort-by-a-field-in-mongoose-in-nodejs. Could you suggest me what should be the passed parameters for sort now?